# NotifyIcon & BalloonTip

Tags: vb.net, notifyicon

I am trying to use NotifyIcon to show some information to the user in VB Net.

It is working well, but when the Balloon Tip closes, I set the NotifyIcon visibility to false, the Notify Icon disappears from the tray as I intended, but with it, the notification in the notification panel disappears as well.

How can I get rid of the icon but keep the notification in the notification panel?

Here is some code to reproduce the issue:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim n As New Notification("I need some cake!", "Hunger", ToolTipIcon.Info, Me.Icon)
    n.ShowBalloon()
End Sub
```

Class Notification

```
Private ni As System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon

Public Sub New(text As String, title As String, icon As ToolTipIcon, ic As Icon)
    Me.ni = New System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon
    ni.Icon = ic
    ni.BalloonTipText = text
    ni.BalloonTipTitle = title
    ni.BalloonTipIcon = icon
    ni.Visible = True


    AddHandler ni.BalloonTipClosed, AddressOf BalloonClosed
End Sub

Public Sub ShowBalloon()
    ni.ShowBalloonTip(20000)

End Sub

Private Sub BalloonClosed(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
    sender.Visible = False
    sender.Dispose()

End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example, as per the Help Centre.

Comment: *"keep the notification in the notification panel"*. Exactly what notification and what notification panel are you referring to? What happens if you don't dispose the `NotifyIcon`>

Comment: BTW, the fact that you can set `Visible` and call `Dispose` directly on `sender` indicates that you have `Option Strict Off`. You should change that immediately in the project properties and fix the typing errors it flags. You should also set it `On` in the VS options, so it is `On` by default for all future projects.

Comment: @jmcilhinney by notification I mean the same message you see in the BalloonTip and Notification Panel, it is the panel you open when you click the small speech bubble right beside the clock on the taskbar - I think in English, it's called notification center.

Comment: @jmcilhinney To put it simply: the generated baloontooltip is not stored at the notification center after the NotifyIcon visibility is set to false.